# VBA Delete row based on 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that will delete the entire row if a cell in a column has red text

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Intersect(Columns("L"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then Cell.Value = "#N/A"
Next
On Error GoTo NoRedText
Columns("L").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete

NoRedText:
```

I would like to extend this code to also include another column that includes a "Y" value in the cell.

Column L includes the red text string

Column P includes the "Y" text string

Therefore if the text is red in column L AND the text is equal to "Y" in column P it should delete the entire row

What do I need to add to the code to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe something like `If Cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex = 3 AND Cell.Offset(,4)="Y" Then....`

Comment: Wow you made that look easy. It works perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: I'll add it as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Cell` variable references a range and all the properties that go with it.

The `Offset` property

> Returns a Range object that represents a range that's offset from the
>   specified range.
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx)

Using this knowledge you can tell your code to look at the range that is offset by four columns:

```
If Cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex = 3 AND Cell.Offset(,4)="Y" Then Cell.Value = "#N/A"
```